# LINQ include "&&" operator if value is greater than zero

Tags: c#, linq

The following method returns data when `leaId` and `seaId` are greater than zero.

How should i change the query to return data if only `leaId` is entered?

Due to the `&&` operator nothing is returned since `seaId` is optional and equal to zero.

```
public IQueryable<Stand> GetStand(int leaId, int seaId = 0)
{
     return from c in db.Stands where c.LeaID == leaId && c.SeaID == seaId
            select new Stand
            {
                   //something
            }
}
```

Comment: `if(seaId ==0) return from c in db.Stands where c.LEadID == leadId else <your current query>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split your query in two pieces:

```
IQueryable<Stand> query=db.Stands.Where(c= c.LeaID == leaId);

if(seaId>0)
{
   query=query.Where(c= c.SeaID == seaId);
}
return query.Select(e=>...);
```

Another important thing is you shouldn't project your query using the entity type (`Stand`). In EF you can project over an anonymous type or using a DTO. If you're projecting using a custom class then ignore this last comment.

Comment: Actually the return type "Stand" is a custom class. What bothers me, is that i have to perform two queries. (It is about an api endpoint, if it matters) :)

Comment: @OrElse, you're not executing two queries, you're building a query which is going to be executed when you materialize the result, eg, calling `ToList` or iterating over it

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your method like

```
 public IQueryable<Stand> GetStand(int leaId, int seaId = 0)
    {
         return from c in db.Stands where (c.LeaID == leaId) ||(seaId>0 && c.SeaID == seaId)
                select new Stand
                {
                       //something
                }
    }
```